# Enabling driving distance in Pgrouting

Tags: pgrouting

I would like to enable `pgr_drivingDistance` function fo Pgrouting. I followed this manual: http://pgrouting.org/docs/1.x/install.html, but I can't execute the last step:

```
psql -U postgres -f /usr/share/postlbs/routing_dd.sql routing
psql -U postgres -f /usr/share/postlbs/routing_dd_wrappers.sql routing
```

These files don't exist in that addresses. And when I try to change the address from "`/usr/share/postlbs/routing_dd.sql`" to the path to `routing_dd.sql` in pgrouting, I get these errors:

```
psql:/home/user/pgrouting/src/driving_distance/sql/routing_dd.sql:27: ERROR:  permission denied for language c
psql:/home/user/pgrouting/src/driving_distance/sql/routing_dd.sql:37: ERROR:  permission denied for language c
psql:/home/user/pgrouting/src/driving_distance/sql/routing_dd.sql:80: ERROR:  must be owner of function pgr_pointsaspolygon
```

Until this step, everything goes well (and I really don't forget to compile Pgrouting with DrivingDistance functionality).

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Pgrouting with driving distance should be installed and enabled now, but when using `drivingDistance` function, I'm getting this error:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 114, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    cursor2.execute("SELECT id1::int4,cost::float8 from pgr_drivingDistance(%s, %s::int4, 10.0,false,false)", [query, source])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
DatabaseError: error with no message from the libpq
[06/Apr/2014 09:05:46] "POST /map/findroute/ HTTP/1.1" 500 16972
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 129, in finish_response
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 36, in close
    SimpleHandler.close(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 257, in close
    self.result.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/response.py", line 308, in close
    signals.request_finished.send(sender=self._handler_class)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 185, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 94, in close_old_connections
    conn.close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 462, in close_if_unusable_or_obsolete
    if self.is_usable():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 192, in is_usable
    self.connection.cursor().execute("SELECT 1")
InterfaceError: connection already closed
[06/Apr/2014 09:05:46] "POST /map/findroute/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 53783)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 582, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 126, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 638, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 124, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 89, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 304, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 127, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 210, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 267, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 280, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to the wrong documentation (the old version).
The pgRouting 2.0 documentation is available here: http://docs.pgrouting.org/

It's important that pgRouting has been [built with support for driving distance](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/doc/src/installation/build.html). This should be the case for binaries, but if you compile yourself, you need to enable it with the flag `-DWITH_DD=ON`.

If driving distance is available, then "CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting;" is all you need to do to install the functions in your database.

Comment: Thank you, so in this case it should work now, but it doesn't (I added to my question what error I'm getting).

Comment: Please could you post your query without Django but only SQL?